# Binary Search to find k-least number in an unrolled linked list

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list, binary-search

I store sequence in an unrolled linked list to deal with other operations(insert, delete, reverse), and I maintain sorted array after each operation in each node to implement efficient k-least query.
I use two kind of binary search, one in k-least function, and the other in lessCount and lessthanCount. Given the number is between 10^5 and - 10^5, the first kind is to find whether *mid* is the bigger or less than k-least number. The second kind is to binary search in each node and add up the results, to obtain the order range of *mid*.

I think the time complexity is O(lg(arraysize)*n/arraysize), and I set arraysize = sqrt(n) to strike the balance between k-least query and other operation.

However, the program is still not efficient enough. Is there any way to boost the k-least query operation while not adjust arraysize?

```
int lessCount(int x, LinkNode *node){
    if (node->size == 0)
        return 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = node->size;
    while (left < right){
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (node->sorted[mid] >= x){
            right = mid;
        }else if (node->sorted[mid] < x) {
            left = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
int lessthanCount(int x, LinkNode *node){
    if (node->size == 0)
        return 0;
    int left = 0;
    int right = node->size;
    while (left < right){
        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (node->sorted[mid] <= x) {
            left = mid + 1; 
        }else if (node->sorted[mid] > x) {
            right = mid;
        }
    }

    return left;
}
int k_least(LinkNode *start, LinkNode *end, int nodeLen, int k){
    LinkNode *ptr;
    int max = 100001;
    int min = -100000;
    int mid = (max + min) / 2;
    while (true){
        int lower = 0, upper = 0;
        ptr = start;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeLen; i++){
            lower += lessCount(mid, ptr);
            upper += lessthanCount(mid, ptr);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        lower += lessCount(mid, end);
        upper += lessthanCount(mid, end);
        if (k <= lower){
            max = mid - 1;
            mid = (max + min) / 2;
        }else if (k > upper){
            min = mid + 1;
            mid = (max + min) / 2;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return mid;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be an unrolled linked list?

Comment: Concerning there are a huge amount of operation (max 50000) including deletion, insert, and reverse and the length of sequence may be up to 50000, I can't figure out any other data structure.

Comment: I would suggest a B-tree. It has the same advantage of array chunks, but it also maintains everything in sorted order. You can extend it to store the number of lesser values in each node, and keep that updated. You can also consider other data structures in the family of self-balancing search trees.